# How to delete a node in OpenStreetMap with the OSM API version 0.6 and curl

Tags: curl, openstreetmap

At first, I gave a try to [the instructions in the official wiki of OpenStreetMap](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Using_curl_to_upload_data) despite the warning about the version 0.6.

The advised method still works when one wants to download the data of a node but the deletion of a node doesn't work:

```
curl -u username:password -X DELETE 'https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/6345940173'
```

[The documentation of the API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6#Delete:_DELETE_.2Fapi.2F0.6.2F.5Bnode.7Cway.7Crelation.5D.2F.23id) states "Expects a valid XML representation of the element to be deleted". What more do I have to do to make it work?

My last attempt doesn't work:

```
curl -u username:password -X DELETE 'https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/6345940173' -T delete.xml
```

delete.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><osm><node id="6345940173" version="1" changeset="68272837" lat="48.8647893" lon="2.4283983"></node></osm>
```

It just tells:

> The changeset 68272837 was closed at 2019-03-18 21:01:43 UTC

I obtain the same result when I encode the credentials by myself by using `echo -ne username:password|base64 --wrap 0` and when I call `curl -H "Authorization: Basic <my_token>" -X DELETE 'https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/6345940173' -T delete.xml`.

Comment: Never ever run any API tests on the production instance, always start with the dev instance first! In your case, why don't you use the established editors, like JOSM or iD?

Comment: Also, what you're trying to do sounds like you want to read  https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import/Guidelines  *before* continuing, otherwise your edits will get reverted and your user blocked!

Comment: Follow up discussion: https://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=65958

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting a changeset is impossible as it's immutable. I thank mmd for this information. You can see why by carefully looking at this diagram below:
[image: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/w/images/thumb/6/67/OSM_API0.6_Changeset_successful_creation_V0.1.png/600px-OSM_API0.6_Changeset_successful_creation_V0.1.png]

However, the syntax used in my very last attempt seems to be correct and should work with other request methods (PUT, POST).